# Простое if условие не работает, где может быть ошибка?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Скрипт для Unity, но возможно здесь просто оевидная C#  ошибка которую я не вижу...
Имеется скрипт, "печатающий" текст по букве. Он применен к тексту кнопки кнопки (text, потомок button). Нужно чтобы скрипт запускался только если кнопка нажимабельна (interactable).

Я создал публичную переменную чтобыперетащить в нее кнопку в Unity, и использовал GetComponent(), но почему-то не работает.

Ниже короткий скрипт.
Почему это не сработало, где ошибка? Заранее спасибо!

UPD скрипт слегка обновлен но по-прежнему не работает.

---

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

// attach to UI Text component (with the full text already there)

public class UITextTypeWriter : MonoBehaviour {


public Text txt;
string story;
 public Button ThisButton;

void Start()
{
    txt = GetComponent<Text>();
    story = txt.text;
    txt.text = "";



        if (ThisButton.interactable) {
            StartCoroutine(PlayText());
        }
    }

IEnumerator PlayText()
{
    foreach (char c in story)
    {
        txt.text += c;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.125f);
    }
}

}
```

Comment: @ValeraKvip Спасибо большое, это почти то что нужно! Мне нужно чтобы функция срабатывала если кнопка была неактивна но стала активной во время игры. ПРобовал void Update но тогда почему-то пишет безсмыслицу.

Comment: @ValeraKvip Да, спасибо, почти то что нужно но я применяю код к тексту-потомку button, видимо текст и его компоненты не становится disabled когда button disabled. Поэтому скрипт работает только если я вручную отключаю и снова включаю его в инспекторе во время игры... а мне нужно чтобы он запускаля, когда кнопка тановится активной во врем игры.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**isActiveAndEnabled** - вернет **false**, если компонент изначально был активен, и **true** если скрипт был активирован(ГО был не активен, а потом его включили или деактивировали, а затем активировали.) - поправьте меня если я не прав.

```
public Text txt;
string story;
public Button ParrentButton;

void Awake()
{
    txt = GetComponent<Text>();
    story = txt.text;
    txt.text = "";

    ParrentButton = transform.parent.GetComponent<Button>();

}
void OnEnable()
{
    if (ParrentButton.isActiveAndEnabled)
    {
        StartCoroutine(PlayText());
    }
}

IEnumerator PlayText()
{
    foreach (char c in story)
    {
        txt.text += c;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.125f);
    }
}
```

С учетом комментариев (срабатывает при изменение параметра interactable ):

```
public Text txt;
string story;
public Button ParrentButton;
bool JustSwitched;

void Awake()
{
    txt = GetComponent<Text>();
    story = txt.text;
    txt.text = "";
    ParrentButton = transform.parent.GetComponent<Button>();        
}

private void Update()
{
    if(ParrentButton.interactable && !JustSwitched)
    {            
        StartCoroutine(PlayText());
        JustSwitched = true;
    }
    else if (!ParrentButton.interactable && JustSwitched)
    {
        txt.text = "";
        StopAllCoroutines();
        JustSwitched = false;
    }
}


IEnumerator PlayText()
{
    foreach (char c in story)
    {
        txt.text += c;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.125f);
    }
}
```

Comment: Если кнопка была неактивна до запуска игры, после запуска игры функция печати не выполняется, но как сделаь чтобы функция выполнялась после того как я сделал кнопку активной во время игры?

Comment: Пробовал  заключить if (...) в void Update() но происходит что-то странное и набирается безсмыслица.

Comment: юзай  OnEnable..  Кстати это похоже и  и причина почему оно не работало, но в документации как всегда ни слова....

Comment: Я применяю код к тексту потомку button, видимо текст и его компоненты не становится disabled когда button disabled. ПОэтому скрипт работает только если я вручную отключаю и снова включаю его в инспекторе во время игры...

Comment: Супер, спасибо огромное, это то что нужно! :)

Comment: Только  txt.text = ""; можно вернуть во вторую версию, иначе текст дописывается к уже существующему

Comment: Спасибо!!!!!!!!

Comment: @Rumata Да в начале тоже нужно очитстить, сейчас поправлю